# How to return uniqueId in function and show on app page ( react native )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I have a function like this in my class

```
gettac = () => {
    uniqueId((error,id) => {
        if (error) return console.error(error)
        console.log(id)
        return id
    })
}
```

this code will print id in log (eg: 12345-56789-98555). But how can i show the id in my app page?
I had try `<Text>{this.gettac()}<Text/>` but seems like it doesn't work.And i think the problem is because of `return id` doesn't return the id for me.
FYI, this is my reference link https://github.com/stockulus/react-native-unique-id

Comment: Are you passing in a callback function to `uniqueId()`?

Comment: You need to return `uniqueId()`

Comment: i try to put `return uniqueID((error,id) => ......` but still not able to get the id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why gettac is needed. From the code it seems that only uniqueID is doing something, and you can just write:

```
 uniqueId(error, id) {
   if (error)
     return console.error(error);
   console.log(id);
   return id;
 }
```

And then, in render()

```
<Text>{this.uniqueId(error, id)}</Text>
```

But if you want to keep both, you probaly need to write:

```
 gettac(error, id) {
   return this.uniqueID(error, id);
 }

 uniqueId(error, id) {
   if (error)
     return console.error(error);
   console.log(id);
   return id;
 }
```

Comment: Updated. Please check now.

Comment: I think error and id shouldn't pass by me.
https://github.com/stockulus/react-native-unique-id
I'm following this to get unique id of my phone, but it only show how to display the id in log, so now im trying to display the id in my app page.